# EMI filter SMPS

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, emi-filtering

I was wandering how the main voltage coming from main in SMPS is not attenuated by the  EMI filters. This is the input stage of a AC/DC SMPS by TI (https://www.ti.com/tool/PMP11064):
[image]

Maybe I'm wrong but the 230VAC voltage coming from the mains is differential by nature so why does this 1mH choke not attenuate this voltage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Maybe I'm wrong but the 230VAC voltage coming from the mains is
> differential by nature so why does this 1mH choke not attenuate this
> voltage?*

Because both L802 and L803 are **common-mode chokes** i.e. they attenuate common-mode noise in both directions and leave differential AC signals (such as the mains) largely unaffected. That is their purpose --> it's all about the dots on each winding: -

[image]

If there dots were at opposite ends then the choke would become a differential mode choke.

Comment: Sorry should have specified how the X-capacitor C805 filters the differential noise but why does it not suppress the input voltage signal?

Comment: *why does* **it** *not suppress the input voltage signal* <-- why does **what** not suppress?

Comment: the X-capacitor

Comment: At 50 Hz it has an impedance of nearly 7 kohm. The AC supply has probably got an effective impedance of around a few ohms hence, the capacitor barely loads the AC source at all and barely creates any measurable attenuation. It's not meant to either.